# How to solve "incorrect syntax near '(' while combining multiple tables into 1 new table?

Tags: syntax

I am creating new table as combined_data and want to combine multiple other tables into it
here is my error snippet  --- my sql software is [sql server management studio 19]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPdpc.jpg)

here is my code:

create table   combined_data as (
select * from janmar
union all
select * from aprjune
union all
select * from july
union all
select * from aug
union all
select * from sept
union all
select * from octdec
)